# Is this mold? What next?

Tags: repair, mold, new-home

Went to do some cleaning in the garage, noticed some black lines on the ceiling. Also had noticed something on the ceiling of the main bathroom for some time before noticing the spots in the garage.
The garage and attic are not temperature controlled, the main floor and the basement have a retrofitted central air. Ranch house with one main floor, and an small attic above, on a slope so the basement is under the kitchen/living room/main bath and extends to to a garage that is underneath the bedrooms but can walkout from it.
Note: it has a been an extremely rainy season, so the mold may have appeared faster than it would have normally

Not very handy. Help!

Pictures of suspected mold: https://imgur.com/a/WqojBIN

[image: 1]
[image: 1]
[image: 1]
[image: 1]

Comment: @asinine bleach mix? what ratio? just spray and let it dry?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Ha, I updated the question in include the images. Sorry I am new here.

Comment: It does look like you have small leak above the ceiling that would feed mold growth

Comment: @jjj concentrated or 50/50

Comment: Or this? [Mold on drywall. Should I clean-up or replace?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/30185/mold-on-drywall-should-i-clean-up-or-replace)

Comment: Or this? [Is this black mold/wall damage fixable without professional help?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/202474/is-this-black-mold-wall-damage-fixable-without-professional-help)

Comment: Or this? [Should I open up the ceiling due to this mold-like substance?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/281072/should-i-open-up-the-ceiling-due-to-this-mold-like-substance)

Comment: That wasn't a _small_ leak. It takes a lot of water to run down a joist that far and into the corner. Check your roof.